# SQL trigger email unique

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I want to create a trigger (and not a constraint) to verify if an email exists already. If so, the trigger raises an error. If not, the email is inserted into the table.

I started with this but it isn't working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER3 
       BEFORE INSERT ON FV_CLIENT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT COURRIEL FROM FV_CLIENT
            WHERE COURRIEL=:new.courriel) THEN

     raise_application_error(-20001,'Courriel deja existant, choisir une autre combinaison courriel/Mot de passe');          
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Why would you want to use a much less efficient and much more error-prone trigger when you can use a much more efficient declarative constraint?  Unless this is a homework problem, I don't see why you'd ever go down that path.

Comment: Sometime trigger-based solution preferred because of ability to generate meaningful error description and generate different error codes.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the command `raise_application_error` I guess it's an ORACLE database. Assuming you have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE FV_CLIENT (
   COURRIEL VARCHAR2(48)
);
```

you could use this trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER3 
BEFORE INSERT ON FV_CLIENT FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  CURSOR check_curriel IS
  SELECT 1
    FROM FV_CLIENT 
   WHERE COURRIEL = :new.COURRIEL;
   x VARCHAR2(48);
BEGIN
  OPEN check_curriel;
  FETCH check_curriel INTO x;
  IF NOT check_curriel%NOTFOUND THEN
    CLOSE check_curriel;
    raise_application_error(-20001,'Courriel deja existant, choisir une autre combinaison courriel/Mot de passe');
  END IF;
  CLOSE check_curriel;
END;
```

First two `INSERT`'s without error:

```
INSERT INTO FV_CLIENT VALUES ('mon.pere@paris.fr');
INSERT INTO FV_CLIENT VALUES ('mon.frere@lyon.fr');
```

Third `INSERT` throws the exception as intended:

```
INSERT INTO FV_CLIENT VALUES ('mon.pere@paris.fr');
```

> Fehlerbericht - SQL-Fehler: ORA-20001: Courriel deja existant, choisir
>   une autre combinaison courriel/Mot de passe ORA-06512: at
>   "SCOTT.TRIGGER3", line 11 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger
>   'SCOTT.TRIGGER3'

***p.s.***: as per comment of Justin Cave using the trigger above might result in a mutating table exception, for instance:

```
INSERT INTO FV_CLIENT 
SELECT COURRIEL 
  FROM FV_CLIENT 
 WHERE COURRIEL = 'mon.pere@paris.fr';
```

returns

> 4091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
>         *Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
>                this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
>                in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
>         *Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.

So it's usually recommended to use a `UNIQUE` constraint. Thanks for the note!

Comment: This trigger will generate a mutating table exception if you ever do an `INSERT SELECT` into the table.  In general, row level triggers on a particular table are not allowed to query the table on which they are defined.

Comment: @Justin Cave: good point, you are absolutely right. Do you have a better solution using a trigger?

Comment: A trigger based solution would generally need three triggers and a package with a collection of primary keys (or a temporary table) so it generally gets a lot more complicated.

Comment: Now I remember: it's quite some years ago ;) I used something like described here: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/ASKTOM.download_file?p_file=6551198119097816936